# MySQL select rows from one table not in another for specific dates

Tags: mysql, join

I've two table individuals and Staff login times as mention bellow. I want to fetch staff members those who are not logged In on specific date.

```
individuals
+----+------+--------------+
| id | name | phone_number |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | Smith | 1234567897 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 2  | David | 9874561237 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | John | 7778889991 |
+----+------+--------------+

staff_login_times
+----+------+--------------+
| id | individual_id | login_date |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | 2             | 2017-02-27 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 2  | 1             | 2017-02-26 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | 2             | 2017-02-26 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 4  | 3             | 2017-02-26 |
+----+------+--------------+
```

How do I find out individuals not present on 27th

```
Result
+----+------+--------------+
| id | name  | phone_number |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | Smith | 1234567897   |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | John  | 7778889991   |
+----+------+--------------+
```

Query I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM individuals
LEFT JOIN staff_login_times ON individuals.id = staff_login_times.individual_id
WHERE staff_login_times.individual_id IS NULL
  AND staff_login_times.login_date = '2017-02-27'
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I've tried this query : SELECT * FROM individuals LEFT JOIN staff_login_times ON individuals.id = staff_login_times.individual_id WHERE staff_login_times.individual_id IS NULL AND staff_login_times.login_date = '2017-02-27';

Comment: I think you should do that condition login_date != '2017-02-27' or that login_date < '2017-02-27'

Comment: try this `SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM individuals
LEFT JOIN staff_login_times ON individuals.id = staff_login_times.individual_id
WHERE staff_login_times.login_date != '2017-02-27' `

Comment: I've tried but its not working...

Comment: returns duplicate rows  login_date < 2017-02-27

Comment: Besides,`DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron

Answer (score 1):

Just small change, use your and condition with join statement:-

```
SELECT *
FROM individuals
LEFT JOIN staff_login_times ON individuals.id = staff_login_times.individual_id AND staff_login_times.login_date = '2017-02-27'
WHERE staff_login_times.individual_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need join

try this

```
select * from individuals 
where id not in 
(select individual_id from staff_login_times where login_date = '2017-02-27');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
SELECT a.id, a.`name`, a.phone_number, b.login_date FROM individuals a LEFT JOIN 
staff_login_times b on a.id = b.individual_id WHERE b.login_date <> "2017-02-27";
```

Comment: It returns all the records from the table login date < 2017-02-27 any other solution? thanks for such appreciable efforts...

Comment: Hey Dev, i am not entirely sure I understand what you require at this point, can you help me understand what exactly you want the query to return and I am sure i can help.

Comment: I just want to display individuals those who are not logged-In on specific date as you see on 27th Feb 2017 Smith and john not logged-In. After your suggestions I've filtered query and tried this query (SELECT DISTINCT(a.id), a.`name` FROM individuals a LEFT JOIN staff_login_times b on a.id = b.individual_id WHERE (b.login_date <> "2017-02-27") ORDER BY `a`.`id` ASC) not only problem is it returns logged-in users also...

Comment: If i get you right then the first answer from Rakesh Kumar gives you want you need ------> SELECT a.id, a.`name`, a.phone_number FROM individuals a
LEFT JOIN staff_login_times b ON a.id = b.individual_id AND b.login_date = '2017-02-27' WHERE b.individual_id IS NULL;

Answer (score -1):

Another option you can use , is to expand `where` condition instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
  SELECT individuals.id ,individuals.name FROM individuals ,staff_login_times WHERE 
staff_login_times.login_date = '2017-02-27'
AND staff_login_times.individual_id  != individuals.id ;
```